# how to replace single quote with string in javascript

Tags: c#

I have some data from a lookup like this: `=winz\ach'dull`.
How can I replace single quotes (') with ("").

This is my code =>

```
<input type="button" id="btnSelect" onclick="Select('<%#Eval("LoginName").ToString().Replace("'", "\'")%>');" value="Select"/>
```

I'm trying to create code like this:

```
Select('<%#Eval("LoginName").ToString().Replace("'", "\'")%>');
```

but it does not not work.

Please correct and help me. Thanks.

Comment: well, that's clearly not javascript, what is it?

Comment: upzzz,, sorry.. The code in c # :)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape quotes with the "`\`" character and it works perfectly with HTML. So the answer to exactly what you wrote would be: (this is just to humour you in the future)

```
"Select('<%#Eval(\"LoginName\").ToString().Replace(\"'\", \"\'\")%>');"
```

But you have syntax errors in what you are writing and that Eval stuff is not javascript so I don't know why ToString and Replace are attached to it. I've changed it a little based on guessing what you're trying to do:

```
<input onclick="Select('<%#Eval("LoginName")%>').ToString().Replace(\"'\", \"'\");">
```

Note that if you're using C# or something on the server side it doesn't need to be escaped because by the time the HTML is parsed in the DOM, typically a browser the source no longer contains your server side code and only the output!

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript we could do :

```
var a="winz\ach'dull.";
alert(a.replace("'",'"'));
```

And that would replace your single quote.

Note: Your code is C# not javascript.